# Store Github / Gitea authentication token with passphrase like SSH keys

Tags: git, authentication, github, encryption, ssh

I currently work with git repositories where ssh protocol is disabled.

I use to work with ssh and store my ssh token with a passphrase.
Now that I need to use without ssh I would like to store my token with the same methodology.

The goal is that I can pull and push my git repo with the same method whatever the authentication is ssh or api token.

I don't really want to store token on my disk without encryption.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS URL, where credentials (username / token as password) are used, you would need to:

- install (unless you are using Git for Windows, on Windows) [Microsft Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) (cross-platform, Windows, Linux or Mac)
  Make sure the `git-credential-maanger-core` executable is in your PATH (Linux/Mac `$PATH`, or Windows `%PATH%`)
- configure Git

  ```
   git config --global credential.helper manager-core
  ```

That way, your token will be cached in the native credential manager (Windows Credential Manager on Windows, libsecret on Linux, osxkeychain on Mac)